# Is it possible to keep an external user (community user) logged in indefinitely?

Tags: apex, community, connected-apps, session

I have a connected app that is using Salesforce Communities to provide Salesforce support for my app.  I'd like to have the users not get logged out at all.  The highest setting is "Session times out after   24 hours of inactivity".  Is there a way to code around this to update the user session so they external community user will only have to sign in once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can depend on the specifics of your external application and authentication set up, but ideally your connected app would use the [OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm) to persist the access token.